# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, unhandled-exception

I'm trying to open a document in either of two files using the below code:

```
try
{
    startInfo.FileName = "WINWORD.EXE";
}
catch(Win32Exception)
{
    startInfo.FileName = "TMViewer.exe";
}
```

I don't have MS Word on my laptop so I was hoping the catch would trigger it to open in a Word viewer program but I get that message:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
```

I've upadating the registry to pick up the shortcut of running `TMViewer.exe` and it actually works on my other PC but if I try to run it on my laptop that doesn't have Word installed I keep getting this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is thrown when you `Start()` the process, not when you set that option.

However, you don't need to do any of that.
Instead, just set `FileName` to the document you're trying to open, and Windows will automatically open it in the user's associated program.